# No rows returned when column has a null value - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using sql-server 2012 . There are two tables.

tblFeatures

```
fid  name    subname
-------------------------
10   Size     height
11   Size     Weight
12   Display  Type
13   Display  color
```

tblItems

```
cid   price  value    fid
-------------------------
1001  100    xyz      1
1001  100    2cm      10
1001  100    3gm      11
1002  300    abc       1
```

The output now is

```
 SELECT i.cid,i.price,i.value,f.name,f.subname 
 FROM tblItems i
 LEFT JOIN tblFeatures f on i.fid=f.fid 

cid   price  value  fname fsubname
----------------------------------
1001  100    xyz    NULL     NULL
1001  100    2cm    Size     height
1001  100    3gm    Size     weight
1002  300    abc    NULL     NULL
```

Is it possible to get it like this:

```
cid   price  value  fname fsubname
----------------------------------
1001  100    xyz    NULL      NULL
1001  100    2cm    Size     height
1001  100    3gm    Size     weight
1001  100           display  type
1001  100           display  color
1002  300    abc    NULL      NULL    
1002  300           Size     height
1002  300           Size     weight
1002  300           display  type
1002  300           display  color
```

I tried a right join, but no luck

Please check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f82c08/2)

Comment: downvote without a reason aint helping

Comment: Why doesn't your fiddle match your question sample? Please, to remove dependency from external sites add the code of your fiddle also here.

Comment: unless you explain it a little better, this makes not sense at all. Why would the 4th and 5th desired rows of your result have a price of 100, and not any other price? -1

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Completely rewrote my answer, as I think I understand your question now.

Try something like this:

```
WITH UniqueItems AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT cid, price
     FROM Items
)
SELECT t.cid,t.price,i2.value,t.name,t.subname 
  FROM (select * from UniqueItems i, Features f) t
LEFT JOIN Items i2 ON i2.cid = t.cid AND i2.fid = t.fid

 UNION ALL

SELECT cid, price, value, null, null
  FROM Items
 WHERE fid = 1

ORDER BY cid, name
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f82c0/4/0)

To elaborate a bit about my comment below: This is a perfect example of one of the consequences of bad data modeling: Queries that ought to be simple, are very difficult to write and understand. Since you don't have a table that actually holds the item entities, we need to construct this table in our query (this is why we have the CTE with `SELECT DISTINCT`). Furthermore, since the fid-column of the Items-table holds records that doesn't refer anything in the Features table, we need to explicitly handle this in a union. Also, you have redundant data in the Items table - the price for item with cid 1001 is duplicated... this is bound to get you into trouble later on.

A much better - and simpler - data model could look like this:

```
Items (cid, price, name, weight, height, type, color)
```

If you must have item "features" as records instead of columns, you should use at least 3 tables:

```
Items (cid, price)
Feature (fid, fname, fsubname)
ItemFeature (cid, fid, value)
```

Comment: oh no. Not all combinations. I only want to include evn null rows. If i run your query, I get 3gm even for size-height, which is not logical. I have mentioned the desired o/p in question

Comment: I have rewritten my answer - it should give the correct result now. By the way: Your data model sucks :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check with full join

```
SELECT i.cid,i.price,i.value,f.name,f.subname 
 FROM tblItems i
 FULL OUTER tblFeatures f on i.fid=f.fid
```